# Bower and Asset Precompilation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, bower

this may be a case of me missing a completely obvious solution, but I've tried several approaches by now and feel lost.

The current situation is that I have a Rails project that uses bower for managing frontend assets (jQuery, Angular.. you get the idea). I used both the bower-rails gem and a "vanilla" bower.json to write the dependencies to vendor/assets/bower_components.

I can use everything fine in dev-mode, since I don't use uglifier there to preprocess assets. But in production mode, some assets – like jQuery – fail to compile. This is because uglifier tries to compile and uglify the source files for jQuery and not only using stuff that's in the dist-folder (which is, you guessed right, prepared for distribution).

What I'd like to do is only include the distribution-relevant files from the files provided via bower in my precompilation phase – and i have no idea how to get there.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly define what you want to precompile in `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(dist/*)
```

By default it precompiles *application.js* and *application.css* and some other stuff, you can override this behavior if you do not want them to be precompiled.

Take a look at [Rails official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), it explains how to use more difficult rules of including assets for precompilation.

Comment: Alright, I figured that I can customize what is loaded and write the required logic myself, but .. I hoped that somebody already did that. For now, I just turned off asset precompilation and everything is fine with just-in-time compilation of those.